# Brand new smoke detector chirping

Tags: electrical

One of our hard wired smoke detectors was chirping. We purchased new 10 year detectors. When a new one is installed in that location it chirps. Also traded with another location and it chirps in that location. Even removed it entirely in that location and it still chirps.

Comment: Could be defective, have a bad battery(for power outage).  If it is new, return it.  Did you follow the directions for installing it?

Comment: Is that location unusually hot, cold, or dusty/dirty/cobwebby?

Comment: Did you replace the battery with known good one ?

Comment: @Ruskes the 10 year detectors normally have a non replaceable battery

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you for sharing your opinion, even if it is false.  My 20 Yr had replaceable 9 V battery

Comment: @Ruskes I very **specifically** said **10** year. In ye olden times, most smoke detectors came with replaceable 9 volt batteries. There were two problems: 1 - Many people didn't bother to replace the batteries when they went dead, resulting in useless smoke (non-)detectors; the advice was replace (or at least check) the batteries twice a year at spring-forward/fall-back time - many people did, many did not; 2 - The detectors themselves wear out over time for a variety of reasons, and people would just keep blindly replacing batteries assuming nothing else could ever go wrong. The "10 year"

Comment: detectors are an attempt to solve both problems: By including a *non-replaceable long-life* battery, they avoid the need for periodic battery changes. And by including a timer, they signal (assuming the battery hasn't gone dead first) when they are at "end of life". This is not a simple thing - there are pros (more likely that the typical detector is less than 10 years old and functioning well) and cons (detectors that might otherwise last for 10 years sometimes die early due to bad batteries, which I suspect is OP's problem; detectors that might be totally functional for 15 years have to be

Comment: replaced at 10 years. But this is not my *opinion*. It is based in facts. See for example [this MD law](https://www.dllr.state.md.us/labor/build/smokealarmlawfiremarshall.pdf) and [this Illinois law](https://www.ifsa.org/prevention-resources/smoke-alarm-law/) etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact As I said, u r wrong. The one with 9V battery will alert you with very loud signal to replace the batter, so it can not be forgotten.

Comment: What does the detector's manual say that the chirping means?

Comment: I agree, @Ruskes, my smoke detectors chirp when the batteries die. _However_, mine are _NOT_ the 10-year, fixed battery types. The OP has specified that he purchased the 10-year, non-replaceable battery types, since replacing the battery in these is not a user serviceable option, "u r wrong".

Answer (score 1):

I have tried 3 different brands over the last few years. Including the one recommended by the local Fire Service (here in New Zealand). They are all rubbish. About 10 to 15 percent fail within a few months to a few years. I got sick of returning them for replacements.

So I  use wired ones now.

It won't stop chirping unless you replace the battery. We used to put it  under an upside down bucket, outside the house until I could return it.

If your retailer won't replace it, just keep queuing in lines again and again. It will drive every one nuts.